# Helmholtz - Kirchoff Integral theorem - geometrical construction

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, diffraction

I'm going through this subject in J. Goodmans' book - Fourier Optics, and  the following geometrical construction is made:
[image]

The goal of this construction is to exclude $P_0$ from the surface S.
Therefore, a new ***composite surface*** is proposed which is:
$S' = S + S_\epsilon$

My question is:

Shouldn't it be :

$S' = S - S_\epsilon$

Since we are **removing** the small bubble around $P_0$ from S?

Cheers

Comment: you have "added" a new piece of surface, but removed a piece of volume.

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: originally you had a volume $\mathcal V$ (not shown) that was bounded by a surface $\mathcal S=\partial \mathcal V$ (shown). From within $\mathcal V$ there is a point $\mathcal P_0$ surrounded by a volume $\mathcal V_{\epsilon}$ whose boundary is $\mathcal S_{\epsilon}=\partial \mathcal V_{\epsilon}$, you remove $\mathcal V_{\epsilon}$ now what remains has boundary $\mathcal S'=\mathcal S_{\epsilon} \cup \mathcal S$

Comment: This is exactly what I can't manage to understand.
If you argue that you remain with boundary $ S' = S_\epsilon U S$, than this must mean that $S$ is included in $S'$. However, this means that $P_0$ would stil be inside $S'$, no?

Comment: That is true but now you have a new "surface" and along with it a new "surface source"; diffraction phenomenon (and its "Helmholtz-Kirchhoff" integral representation) is induced by surface or edge currents/charges. This is analogous the way magnetic charges are induced on a magnetizable body when immersed in an external field.